# How to incorporate cross-object logic on domain class using Apex Enterprise Patterns

Tags: apex, design-patterns, domain-layer

Using the Apex Enterprise Patterns, I would like to incorporate cross-SObject logic in my domain class. Is the following example a correct implementation?

Interaction__c records are created with references to Channel__c records. By default, certain fields of the Interaction__c record such as OwnerId are dependent on the referenced Channel__c record. Thus:

InteractionsTriggerHandler

```
public class InteractionsTriggerHandler extends fflib_SObjectDomain
{
    public InteractionsTriggerHandler(List<Interaction__c> sObjectList)
    {
        // Domain classes are initialised with lists to enforce bulkification throughout
        super(sObjectList);
    }

    public override void onApplyDefaults()
    {
        setChannelSpecificValues();
    }

    private void setChannelSpecificValues()
    {
        IInteractions interactions = Interactions.newInstance(this.Records);
        interactions.setChannelSpecificValues();
    }
```

Interactions domain class

```
public class Interactions extends fflib_SObjects 
    implements IInteractions
{
    // boilerplate initializers ommitted

    public void setChannelSpecificValues()
    {
        Set<Id> channelIds = getChannelIds();
        IChannels channels = Channels.newInstance(channelIds);
        channels.applyAttributesToInteractions( (List<Interaction__c>) getRecords() );
    }

    public Set<Id> getChannelIds()
    {
        Set<Id> result = new Set<Id>();
        for (Interaction__c record : (List<Interaction__c>) getRecords())
        {
            if (record.Interaction_Channel__c != null)
            {
                result.add(record.Interaction_Channel__c);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Channels domain class

```
public class Channels extends fflib_SObjects
    implements IChannels
{
    // boilerplate initializers ommitted

    public void applyAttributesToInteractions(List<Interaction__c> interactions) 
    {
        Map<Id, List<Interaction__c>> channelIdToInteractions = new Map<Id, List<Interaction__c>>();
        for (Interaction__c interaction : interactions)
        {
            if (interaction.Interaction_Channel__c == null) continue;

            if (!channelIdToInteractions.containsKey(interaction.Interaction_Channel__c))
                channelIdToInteractions.put(interaction.Interaction_Channel__c, new List<Interaction__c>{interaction});
            else
                channelIdToInteractions.get(interaction.Interaction_Channel__c).add(interaction);
        }

        for (Channel__c record : (List<Channel__c>) getRecords())
        {
            if (!channelIdToInteractions.containsKey(record.Id)) continue;

            for (Interaction__c interaction : channelIdToInteractions.get(record.Id))
            {
                interaction.OwnerId = record.OwnerId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it correct that although the interaction records are being inserted, we initialize a Channels domain class and have that handle the updates to the interaction record?

Comment: i'd avoid domain classes (Channels) calling other domain classes (Interactions) to set values - the Interactions domain is responsible for managing its data fields, especially in `onApplyDefaults`

Comment: thank you for the guidance. It helped me understand that I should encapsulate logic that alters the Interactions object within the Interactions.cls domain class itself. I would just fetch the Channel__c records I need through its selector and work through the logic from within a method in the Interactions domain class, and call that method on the TriggerHandler class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What goes in a domain class versus a service class is a subject of much debate but for your `Interactions` domain class, method `onApplyDefaults` you should query via the `ChannelsSelector` to get channels values and use `Interactions`-specific logic to default `Interaction__c` fields.

That is, `Interactions` is responsible for defaulting its own values, don't have `Channels` domain execute logic that sets `Interactions`' domain values

If you reference Chapter 6 of the Salesforce Platform Lightning Enterprise Architecture book by Andy Fawcett, you can see a couple of examples where service classes call the domain class to *update* data in a manner where the domain is responsible for its SObject field values (see `RaceService.cls` calling domain `Contestants.cls` to `awardChampionshipPoints()`.  This approach generally requires passing a `unitOfWork` object

Note here, the stimulus event is originating with a Race completion and the domain classes are servants to this stimulus.

But in your OP, it is an `Interaction` that is being inserted, presumably from the UX so `Interactions.cls` needs to take sole responsibility for defaulting its values. Other domains and service classes could be used to assist `Interactions.cls` by wrapping selector-fetched objects that simplify a complex data model into something more easily digestible by `Interactions.cls`

Comment: Thanks again. I could definitely purchase that book and start reading up on it. I ended up with an approach very similar to what you described and it makes sense. Regarding your final point, I believe you describe something akin to OpportunityInfo.cls used by the OpportunitySelector.cls, and I shall keep that in mind.

Comment: @parsa_047Fletcher - the book is seminal; get 3rd Edition (as of 2023-03-01); the chapter on Unit Testing and how apexMocks works with Enterprise Patterns was very helpful to me